Hamburger menu error javascript on mobile site
my site: https://www.dcidentalclinic.com/
I have a big problem. I use smilepure theme and on mobile device, hamburger menu firstly loading wide and than normal, but this situation is bad and loading page 5-7 second. below image, How can I resolve this problem? can you help me?
enter image description here
I used litespeed cahce plugin but dont resolve this problem.


Try below solutions and let me know.

Optimize critical CSS.
Defer non-essential JavaScript.
Minify CSS and JavaScript.
Use a CDN.
Check theme settings for unnecessary scripts.
Test with Google PageSpeed Insights or Lighthouse.


minify css and js with lite speed cache, checked theme settings and ı have edit my post with pagespeed insight report.
